# I have having problem with react while starting server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

When I create a new react app using "npx create-react-app app-name" It does work in the beginning but after sometimes when I start server It shows error

Starting the development server...

```
events.js:298
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/ashim/Desktop/all-react/clone-netflix/public/logo512.png'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (internal/fs/watchers.js:169:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1366:34)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/ashim/Desktop/all-react/clone-netflix/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/ashim/Desktop/all-react/clone-netflix/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/ashim/Desktop/all-react/clone-netflix/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/ashim/Desktop/all-react/clone-netflix/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:262:21)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/ashim/Desktop/all-react/clone-netflix/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:495:21)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:5)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/ashim/Desktop/all-react/clone-netflix/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:260:10)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/ashim/Desktop/all-react/clone-netflix/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/ashim/Desktop/all-react/clone-netflix/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:5) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/home/ashim/Desktop/all-react/clone-netflix/public/logo512.png',
  filename: '/home/ashim/Desktop/all-react/clone-netflix/public/logo512.png'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! clone-netflix@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the clone-netflix@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ashim/.npm/_logs/2020-05-08T05_26_06_564Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions from this [github issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11406) that could help you.

> It’s hitting your system's file watchers limit
>
> Try `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`
>
> Read more about what’s happening at
>   https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details

**OR**

> Alright I restarted the computer, and now everything works fine again.

Comment: I will try that but I have switched text editor and now it works, anyway Thank for your time

Comment: Helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf`
and `$ sudo sysctl -p`